# specman on Komodo

Tags: syntax-highlighting, indentation, komodo, komodoedit, specman

I have 2 problems i can't seem to fix:

1) For some reason Komodo won't highlight any methods in my .e files, even though the default language is specman-E, and the file set to the proper language.
How can i get him to highlight it?

2) After i press enter komodo wont indent properly if inside a function or an "if" statement.
for example:
**what komodo does when i click enter:**

```
if(injection_flag){
gen packet2inject;
};
```

**what should be when i click enter:**

```
if(injection_flag){
    gen packet2inject;
};
```

any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'd be really surprised if komodo supported Specman since Specman is only used for RTL verification tasks which is a small community of people.  If you do get highlighting, I'd bet it was coming from komodo assuming it was the language "eiffel".  There are syntax highlighting modes for VIM and Emacs as can be found on [the wikipedia page for specman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specman).  I have a Specman mode for [JEdit](http://www.jedit.org/), if you want that.

Comment: actually Komodo has specman-E as a language. but for some reason it doesn't do the things i described above.

Comment: Is your code inside `<'` and `'>` which are the Verilog multi-line comment tokens as Specman requires?  (Yeah, this is a basic/newbie thing.)

Comment: Yes it does. yeah its very basic...

Comment: "Yes it does" ? Do you mean that you do have your code inside of `<'` and `'>`, where those tokens are on a line by themselves with nothing else on the line and with a newline after them?

Answer (score 0):

```
<'
    // hello world  
    extend sys
    {
        run() is also
        {
            out ("Hello World");
        };
    };
'>
```

[Smart Indent](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.1/prefs.html#Indentation_Features) does not support specman-E, so indent the initial statement manually with tabs or spaces, then the newline will start at the same level of indentation. Syntax highlighting works, but is very basic.